# React map array of html string and objects to one DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to figure out the best solution to render an array of HTML strings and objects to a single DOM element with the objects being mapped to interact-able React Nodes.

The array looks like this:

```
[
  'Some text<br/><table><tbody><tr><td>Select a date</td><td>',
  {id: 1, type: 'datefield'},
  '</td></tr></table>'
]
```

The second element is ment to be mapped to a field which allows interactions.

The only way I found is to wrap them inside a span but then the table is not rendered properly:

```
elements.map((el: any, index: number)) => {
  if (typeof el === 'string') {
    return (
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: el }} />
    );
  }

  switch(el.type) {
    case 'datefield':
      return <DateField id={el.id} onclick={somehandle}/>
      break;
    default:
      return '';
      break;
  }
}
```

Sorry if I am using the wrong lingo, but I am pretty new to the React game.

Comment: Why it shouldn't work with a `<div>`?

Comment: It breaks the table element.